# Input resistance of OP amplifier

Tags: operational-amplifier

I want to find the input resistance of the following OP-Amp in non-inverting mode. But i have no idea how this may be done. In my book it is calculated in terms of the gain factor and input resistance when the amplifier is modeled as a voltage controlled source. But in this ideal case i dont know how those parameters can be related.[image]

Comment: Hi! The input impedance is Rf in series with whatever the input impedance of the opamp itself is. An ideal opamp has infinite input impedance, so that's also the input impedance of the entire circuit (in the ideal case!).

Comment: Hi! The Wikipedia Article "Operational Amplifier" links to an article on "Operational Amplifier Applications", which has a section on exactly your kind of circuit that answers that! We're very happy to help you once you explain where you need help *after* reading the most reasonably available resources.

Answer (score 1):

The input resistance of an op-amp is infinite in ideal op amps by definition, so there’s nothing to calculate. Rf doesn’t change that: it attaches to an open circuit. It doesn’t matter what building blocks you use to model such an ideal op-amp: its behavior must be ideal or else the model is incorrect and not ideal anymore.

To calculate the DC input resistance of a non-ideal op-amp, you need to know the structure of the input stage, the stage loading the output of the input stage, and at least some of the parameters of the semiconductor devices involved.

Calculating the AC input impedance is more involved since it is heavily affected by parasitics, but often a good approximation is obtained just by looking at the input stage with its bias and loads.

For non-ideal op-amps, without knowing the structure of the op-amp’s internal circuits, the best you can say that the input impedance is greater than Rf, but but it’s not possible to tell how much greater.

As soon as you assume some input stage topology and the bandwidth of the input, you can begin to narrow things down. There are limits to the gain of input transistors and the impedance of their internal load, so the best case can be found out. Real op-amps will have a lower impedance than that optimum. To mode that, you need to know more details of the active and passive devices that form the input stage and its loads.

For current-mode input op-amps, more circuitry is involved, since the input stage has to have a very low impedance and this usually calls for lots of internal gain to divide down the parasitic impedances of the devices that act as voltage sources on the inputs.